# how to update the choicefield queryset after a field is entered in the form in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to make a blogging application in django.
I've created the model for the Blog which has a foreign key to `Category` and `Tag` models.

I want the `Tag` model to be filtered in the `ChoiceField` of forms based on the `category` field entered on the *same form*.

How do i update the queryset of the tags choicefield by entering another choicefield of the form.

Comment: What form is it? `Blog` model form?

Comment: ya its a blog model form.

Comment: @ruddra is right, you can only use ajax to achieve this. Use jquery dropdown change event https://api.jquery.com/change/ to pull dynamically the `Tag` objects you need based on what `category` is selected, then render the result to `tag` dropdown.